# Why doesn't a dll exist in the output path

Tags: c#

I have 3 projects in a one solution:

- a (UnitTest project)
- b (UnitTest project)
- c

a references b (CopyLocal = true), and b references c (CopyLocal = true).

Why doesn't c.dll exist on a's output path?

Comment: in visual studio if you set the `copy to output directory` property for the file to 'Copy Always' I think that will do what you want.

Comment: Not if it is not referenced @Jacobr365

Comment: @Jacobr365 there is no "copy to output directory" property for a reference of a project in the same solution...

Comment: @RoiBar Oh wow, I was selecting the the wrong thing so I had that option. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the code of project a doesn't use directly project b.
(It calls an another class's method which uses (references) b.dll and c.dll...)

Answer (score 1):

Because only referenced projects are included in the build and copied to the output directory. It doesn't matter `b` references `a`. It will just not copy the file.

You need to add a reference to `a` in your project `c`.

Comment: I need c.dll in a's output folder, and for not referencing c directly - I've used CopyLocal = true...

Comment: Why would you need that if the project doesn't use it?